# IIS 7.5 login failed for user login failed to open explicitly specified database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis, iis-7.5

I am hosting asp.net application in iis 7.5 and i am using sql server 2008 R2 its is running fine if i host it outside Default Website and turn its application pool identity to local system at that time my connection string is,

```
<add name="In****" connectionString="Data Source=PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=*****;Integrated Security=SSPI;           Persist Security Info=false; Trusted_Connection=Yes;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

when i tried to run it under default website i deploy it as same but change connection string like,

```
<add name="In*****" connectionString="Data Source=PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=*****;User ID=****;Password=****;Trusted_Connection=False;"/>
```

but i get error,

```
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

i check it alot and get many solution like,

1) Change database name and then try it with sa user by restarting sql services.

2) I also create another user other then sa and attach it with database require for this application.

But error remain same :(

3) I also got solution that in Application pool click default website and then its advance setting then change its identity to Network services.

On this try i got this error,

```
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

Hopes for you suggestion thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you trying to get integrated security working, or are you trying to get your app to use the SQL Server login as your connection string indicates it should? It appears your app is connecting using trusted security despite what you're putting in your connection string.

Comment: @Electric i mentioned my connection strings in my post above please check it out.

Comment: Your first connection string uses integrated security. Your second connection string does _not_ use integrated security and I assume this is the one you are trying to deploy. But all of your troubleshooting explained after this implies you _are_ trying to use integrated security. Which type of login are you trying to get working to gain access to your DB - a windows login or a SQL login? Once we establish that we can try and find a solution.

Comment: To put it another way are you trying to use SQL User User **** to login or are your trying to use the IIS identity (a windows account)?

Comment: I am using my second connection in which i am using id pwd and user used in connection string is not Window login user it is other then that.

Comment: So the real problem is that your application does not appear to be using our connection string. If you change you second connection string to an invalid server what happens? If there is no difference to your error message then it means it is definitely not using your second connection string.

Answer (score 1):

The connection to the database will be established using the security context of the user that is running the IIS application pool. In this case, it is the Network Service local account, which is the one used by default.

I assume that this was working fine during development because you were running Visual Studio with your own user and your user has permissions to this database.

There are a number of solutions for this, some of them not recommended for a production environment, and the final one is my actual recommendation:

- If this database is local, you can give the Network Service account permissions to the database.
- You can use your own account as the user your site's Application Pool will run with, or
- THIS IS THE ONE RECOMMENDED: For production environments, you typically create a domain service account (or local if this is not in the scope of a domain  controller), give it non-admin permissions in the database, but enough to run your app. And then use the same account to run the application pool.

Give permissions to the user to access the DB:http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172405(v=SQL.105).aspx

Assign user to app pool: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=WS.10).aspx

Hope this clarifies

Comment: what i get from your solution is i create new user and in identity i use custom and mention it user id pwd when i run application it give error "Login failed for user 'PC\test'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>]"

Comment: "The connection to the database will be established using the security context of the user that is running the IIS application pool" ONLY IF THE CONNECTION STRING TELLS IT TO. The second connection string does not tell it to - it tells it to use a SQL User, not a windows user.

Comment: What the error suggests is that the user has access to the SQL Server instance but not the DB itself. In SQL Mgmt Stdio go to DB -> Security -> Logins -> <Yours> -> right click Properties -> User Mapping, and map check your DB in the list, with DBO schema and select owner role from below. Note that for security reasons, you should reconsider later the proper role and settings.

Comment: @Adrian i have done and mapped database to the user still then i am getting this error ?? :(

Comment: @Electric i have created Window user and sql user with the same name=test and pwd=123456 but i am not loggin with this user right now.

Comment: @Adrian All what i need is that run my application under Default web site so that this application would be shared on network for that what ever i use either identity=App pool or identity =Network service

Comment: In the Login's Properties window, near the bottom, there is a "Default database" dropdown. It is by default in master, but try changing it to your app's DB. This applies whatever login you decide to use.

Comment: @Adrian i have change it to database that i need but do not know why its not working

Comment: @Adrian if you don't mind can we discuss it on chat ?

Answer (score 0):

Since a little while I'm having the same problem. MY connection string specifically states a user and password to use for logging in. However on *one* of my application pages I'm getting the same error, all others are working perfectly fine.

It worked perfectly fine on my test server previously so I thought it might be due to a received update? So I started de-installing some recent .NET updates and found this:
Initial error:
 Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

Then after de-installing KB2901126 & KB2898869 the error changes to:
 Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\COMPUTERNAME$'.

Note that both of those updates are security patches which prevent users of getting elevated rights:

From KB2901126

> This update resolves vulnerabilities that could allow elevation of privilege if a user visits a specially crafted website or a website that contains specially crafted web content.

So I then wanted to re-install both updates again but I get this message:
[Windows update error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdFVL.png)

Notice the error, [80244022](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-update-error-80244022). The error occurs because of a connection interruption between my server and the update server. Bit weird since the other updates successfully manages to download and install itself.

MS might have removed the updates? I'm not sure what's happening but I'm fairly sure this is happening because of a MS update. No way my "working" app went from working to 1 broken page within 2 weeks without me even updating code from that specific page (or references behind it).

I'm going to try to see whether the same update on my DEV machines could have broken my build.

As a workaround I created a domain account and granted it access to the database, then I switched the app pool to this domain account. Without DB rights, and without editing the connecting string, the error on the specific page changed to "DOMAIN\new account" is unable to access the db. This confirms that for some reason that specific page, and the code behind, disregards the UID & PW in the connection string and uses integrated security.